# An update to BrowserRouter inside a test was not wrapped in act

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to implement my first tests in react with react-test-library, but I came across this certain problem where there's warning that my component is not wrapped in act(..)
[image]

down below is the test that I'm trying to implement

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = render(
      <Router>
        <Search />
      </Router>
    );
  });
  it("handleClick", async () => {
    const button = container.getByText("Search");
    const event = fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(event).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

and Here is the function that I'm trying to test

```
  const handleClick = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const data = await movieAPI.fetchMovieByTitle(movie);
    setLoading(false);
    navigate(`/movie/${data.Title}`, { state: data });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that before doing the assertions we need to wait for the component update to fully complete with waitFor

```
  it("should render spinner", async () => {
    const button = container.getByText("Search");
    const event = await fireEvent.click(button);
    const spinner = container.getByTestId("spinner");
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(spinner).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```